# Read newline character from command line arguments with optparse-applicative

Tags: shell, haskell

Below is an example of a program which takes one optional argument `a` which has as default value the newline character. The program only prints the value of the sole argument. Thus, calling the program with no argument or with `-a '\n'` should give the same value, but it doesn't:

```
$ ./myProg


$ ./myProg -a '\n'
\n
```

The problem is that when it's read from the command line arguments, the newline character is escaped. Is it possible to make the two calls behave the same?

```
import Options.Applicative

data Options = Options String

optsParser :: Parser Options
optsParser = Options
    <$> strOption
         ( short 'a'
        <> metavar "A"
        <> value "\n" )

opts :: IO Options
opts = execParser $ info (helper <*> optsParser) ( fullDesc )

main = do
    Options a <- opts
    putStrLn $ a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not that the newline character is escaped; the problem is that you don't have a newline character in the first place.

As far as the shell is concerned, `'\n'` is literally a two-character string (backslash, n), and that's what gets passed to your program.

How to pass a literal newline character on the command line depends on your shell, but try the following:

```
$ ./myProg -a '
> '
```

(The `>` in there is a secondary shell prompt. What you type is <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>.)

Or in bash:

```
$ ./myProg -a $'\n'
```

Comment: Good clarification. Is there any easy way to make optparse interpret the "\n" given as command line argument as a newline character?

Comment: @GuillaumeChérel You'd have to do that yourself and implement your own escape syntax.